# Global semantic summary mode not enabled at startup

Tags: init-file, semantic-mode

I have used `customize-group` on `semantic` to set `global-semantic-idle-summary-mode` to `t`. My `.emacs` has this entry in `custom-set-variables` : `'(global-semantic-idle-summary-mode t)`.

However, on starting emacs and opening a C++ source file, I don't see the idle summary at point.
On disabling and re-enabling idle summary mode with two calls to `M-x global-idle-summary-mode`, the summary items start showing up.

How do I set this up correctly?

Comment: The custom setting itself does not load semantic. Some custom settings do, but their entry in `custom-set-variables` contains an additional reference to the required library. Maybe you need a `(global-semantic-mode 1)` in your init.el?

Comment: @ChrisR I don't see a customizable variable or a function called `global-semantic-mode`. In the `semantic` customization group, I see a bunch of `global-semantic-*_mode`s. That's where I enabled `summary-mode`.

Comment: I'm not at my computer at the moment, so I can't check. Maybe it's called just `semantic-mode`. You could also try starting Emacs and doing `C-h f global-semantic-idle-summary-mode`. If it tells you that it's an autoloaded function, the problem is that the corresponding library is not loaded.

Comment: @ChrisR You are right - there is a `semantic-mode`. This is customizable as well and I have it set to `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had this problem, then I updated it to latest bzr and the problem goes away. You can checkout the bzr version:

```
bzr checkout bzr://cedet.bzr.sourceforge.net/bzrroot/cedet/code/trunk cedet
cd cedet
make
cd contrib
make
```

Then load your Emacs with the new CEDET. You must load it at the very start of your `init.el` otherwise once the built-in CEDET is loaded, you won't be able to load the bzr version.

As for those global modes, they are actually minor modes and you have to enable it like this:

```
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semanticdb-minor-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-mru-bookmark-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-idle-summary-mode)
(add-to-list 'semantic-default-submodes 'global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode)

(semantic-mode 1)
```